# Всплывающее окно pop-up

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Возникла проблема при оформлении всплывающего окна на JQ.
Суть проблемы заключается в том, что объект закрывается при нажатии на белое поле внутри всплывающего окна.
[image: По задумке, при нажатии на текст задний фон затемняется, и открывается окно. Закрыть его можно при клике по затемнённому полю, либо же по красному квадратику внутри поля.]
Я был бы вам крайне благодарен, если поможете мне с моей проблемой.

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  border: 2px solid red;
  z-index: 999999999999999999;
}

.cancel {
  display: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  height: 10px;
  width: 14px;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 100000000000000000;
}

.cancel:hover {
  background: rgb(255, 50, 50);
}

.fon {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onClick="openPopup(this);">open div1</div>
<div class="fon" onclick="closePopup();">
  <div class="popup">
    This is a test message div1
    <div class="cancel" onclick="closePopup();"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  function openPopup(elem) {
    $(elem).next().fadeIn(200);
    $(elem).next().siblings(".popup").hide();
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  }

  function closePopup() {
    $('.fon').fadeOut(300);
    $('body').css('overflow', 'visible');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

События в js имеют свойство [погружаться и всплывать](https://learn.javascript.ru/bubbling-and-capturing). Поскольку Вы повесили закрытие модалки на клик по фону, то клик по любому из дочерних элементов фона вызывает клик по самому фону и, соответственно, закрытие окна. Чтобы этого не происходило, надо проверять, по какому из элементов кликнули. А для этого нужно убрать инлайновый вызов функции из html-разметки и перенести в скрипты:

```js
  function openPopup(elem) {
    $(elem).next().fadeIn(200);
    $(elem).next().siblings(".popup").hide();
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  }

  function closePopup() {
    $('.fon').fadeOut(300);
    $('body').css('overflow', 'visible');
  }
  
  $('.fon, .cansel').click(function(e) { // при клике проверяем 
    if(e.target.className != 'popup') { // что кликнули не по самому окну
        closePopup(); // и тогда вызываем функцию закрытия окна
    }
  })
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  border: 2px solid red;
  z-index: 999999999999999999;
}

.cancel {
  display: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  height: 10px;
  width: 14px;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 100000000000000000;
}

.cancel:hover {
  background: rgb(255, 50, 50);
}

.fon {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onClick="openPopup(this);">open div1</div>
<div class="fon">
  <div class="popup">
    This is a test message div1
    <div class="cancel"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Вы крайне облегчили мне работу с курсовой!

Comment: @Kugasu, рад помочь )

Answer (score 0):

У Вас ошибка:

```
<div class="fon" onclick="closePopup();">    <------ Вот тут закрываете тоже
  <div class="popup">
    This is a test message div1
    <div class="cancel" onclick="closePopup();"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Соответственно, нужно убрать эвент onclick на div с классом fon

Comment: Всё так и запланировано.
При нажатии на div с классом fon всплывающее окно тоже закрывается.
Реализовано это с целью упросить пользователю пребывание на сайте.

Comment: Тогда подобное поведение нужно описывать

Comment: Виноват, я это описал, но видимо криво это сделал